# RedBeanphp выдаёт ошибку

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp

Браузер выдает ошибку после отправки формы кнопкой submit.

Как можно исправить?

> **Fatal error**: Uncaught exception 'RedBeanPHP\RedException' with message
>   'Plugin 'dispence' does not exist, add this plugin using:
>   R::ext('dispence')' in
>   /var/www/vhosts/alcrew.com/httpdocs/libs/rb.php:12086  Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/vhosts/alcrew.com/httpdocs/signup.php(27):
>   RedBeanPHP\Facade::__callStatic('dispence', Array) #1
>   /var/www/vhosts/alcrew.com/httpdocs/signup.php(27):
>   R::dispence('users') #2 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/vhosts/alcrew.com/httpdocs/libs/rb.php on line 12086

Comment: Написано же, что нету плагина, чтобы установить его следует использовать `R::ext('dispence')`

Comment: Нашел ошибку! не dispenCe, а dispenSe. кажется инглиш стоит поднятуть >.<

Answer (score 1):

не dispen**C**e, а dispen**S**e, синтаксическая ошибка не давала скрипту сработать.